# how to store android application database in every device as well in web server

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an android application in which i used `SQLite` database to store user registration details.I am running my android application in emulator as well as physical device.

What I noticed is that a data of database file under `/data/data/mypackage/databases/dbname.db` is different in emulator as well as in phisical device.
It seems like it stores the data for that particular device only.

My question is how can I store all users data in single database file independent of particular devices and its db files as a owner of my android application.

Because it is necessary for me that i can keep record of all users of my application.
So is there any solution for this.I searched google for this but not get any idea.
thanks in advance

Comment: **Please elaborate your statement** "different in emulator as well as in phisical device. It seems like it stores the data for that particular device"...

Comment: if i add 5 records from emulator then database file under emulator shows only 5 records and if i add 1 new record from my android physical device then database file of my device shows only 1 record that is recently added by device.this db file does not showing previous 5 records that are added from an emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a server and put the applications to synchronise with the server. You can also use services like www.parse.com

Comment: will you please explain me in detail I have not much idea about synchronising with web server